# Laravel Livewire change input value and call component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This is my input

```
<input type="number"  value="1" name="qty" wire:model.debounce.50ms="qty" max="100" min="1">
```

When I enter new input qty will change but I call component which is connected to qty

```
@livewire('site.add-cart', ['qty' => $qty ])
```

But qty do not change in component which is I called , What I can do please give advise...

Comment: Use a backend method or a property for that. If the property has some value (could be true or false) then the nested component

Comment: If I remember correctly, Livewire won't update nested components. Best you can do in that case is use an [event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#firing-events) to send the new value out and catch it within your nested component.